# Excel spreadsheet formula to javascript question

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Hey all i am trying to figure out how to go about calculating this formula from an Excel 2007 fx to javascript:

```
 =(B12*'ROI endo only'!B5)/(1-(1+Data!B12)^(-Data!B13))

 WHERE
   B12 = 0.49%
   B5  = 99,500
   B13 = 48
```

So far i have this as my javascript code:

```
 var theCalc = (0.49 * 99500) / (1 - (1 + 0.49)^(-48));

 alert(theCalc);
```

Though, i am not getting the correct result as what i get on the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has a value of **2,332** and i am getting **-1015.72916...** from the javascript code.

Any help would be great in solving my problem :o)

**UPDATE**

```
 var theCalc = (0.0049 * 99500) / (1 - Math.pow((1 + 0.0049), -48));
```

David

Comment: If B12 is .49%, then shouldn't your javascript variable be .0049 ( = .49%) and not .49 (= 49%)

Comment: Changing the .49 to 0.0049 did the trick with your code, Tommy but how do i round it since the answer is 2331.290084493742 and it should be 2,332?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body onload="testfun();">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function testfun(){
    document.getElementById('testRes').innerHTML = (.0049 * 99500) / (1 - Math.pow((1+.0049), -48));
}
</script>

The answer:
<div id="testRes"></div>
```

This gives a result of 2331.290084493742

Comment: Changing the .49 to 0.0049 did the trick with your code, Tommy but how do i round it since the answer is 2331.290084493742 and it should be 2,332?

Comment: I think we are seeing a little floating point math / rounding error between Excel and JS.  For example, changing my code to this:  ((.0049 * 99500).toFixed(4) / (1 - Math.pow((1+.0049), -48)).toFixed(4)).toFixed(0), gives a result of 2,332.  Basically, using the toFixed properties to limit the number of decimals coming out of each part of the function, then using .toFixed(0) to return the whole number.  I think you're on the right track, just need to see how much precision you need in these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the `^`.  In javascript, `^` does not mean exponent like it does in VB.  You have to use the `Math.pow` method instead.  Try this JavaScript:

```
var theCalc = (0.49 * 99500) / Math.pow( 1 - (1 + 0.49), -48 );
```

Comment: Looking at his original code, I would think the divisor should be (1 - Math.pow((1+.49), -48)

Comment: added a comment to your question and an answer below.  I think it was a combination of what David mentioned, using Math.pow, having your divisor in the correct order and using .0049 instead of .49